# Execute a procedure inside a function (ORA-14551 error)

Tags: oracle, function, procedure, dml

This question is related to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768880/calling-procedure-from-oracle-to-crystal-report).

I have a procedure(`PROC_YEARLYACTIVELIST2`) that will show all records that is active on a specified year.
It will delete the previous contents of `TBLACTIVELISTYEARLY2` and insert the result from `PROC_YEARLYACTIVELIST2`.

I created a function that will execute `TBLACTIVELISTYEARLY2`, Select all records from `TBLACTIVELISTYEARLY` and put it into `CURSOR C_IH`, and return the table for Crystal Report.

Below is just a part of the code:

```
DECLARE
  CURSOR C_IH IS SELECT * FROM tblActiveListYearly2;

  ctr INT;
  i NUMBER;  
  currDeploymentComputer COL_TYPE_DEPLOYMENT_COMPUTER := COL_TYPE_DEPLOYMENT_COMPUTER NULL);
  R_IH C_IH%ROWTYPE;

 BEGIN
 PROC_YEARLYACTIVELIST2(in_year);

  OPEN C_IH;
   i := 0;
    LOOP (....)
```

I've tried to call the function as

```
SELECT GETDEPLOYMENT_COMPUTER('2012') from dual;
```

And has an `ORA-14551` error

```
ORA-14551: cannot perform a DML operation inside a query 
ORA-06512: at "NPLS.PROC_YEARLYACTIVELIST2", line 12
ORA-06512: at "NPLS.GETDEPLOYMENT_COMPUTER", line 3
```

Searched for it and found that it is because of the conflict with `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` and `DUAL`.

Is there any other way to execute my procedure in a function that will return a table?

THANKS!

Comment: Read up on autonomous transactions. Not pretty but probably the only workaround for your situation.

Answer (score 2):

No; for very good reasons you *cannot* perform DML in a SELECT statement.

You're changing the data in the database and Oracle needs a read-consistent view of the data, i.e. it needs to know that what you're selecting is not being changed by what you're selecting.

What you're doing sounds highly unnecessary; you've got a 3 step process:

1. Delete some data from a table
2. Insert new data into that table
3. Select data from the table.

Why not simply select the data you need; it'll be a lot quicker? If you have to pre-process the data then you can have a procedure that does this asynchronously to the selecting of the data.

I don't know anything about Crystal Reports but you can also do this in a PL/SQL block.

```
declare
   l_getdeployment my_variable_type;
begin
   l_getdeployment := GETDEPLOYMENT_COMPUTER('2012');
end;
/
```

Comment: Yes, you're right! I did just select what I want and return using function. And disregard the `TBLACTIVELISTYEARLY2`. Thanks for your response! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to separate DML changes and reporting part. Procedure that does data changes should be called outside of your report function call...

Comment: But how? I can put my procedure in my crystal report but I guess crystal can't process oracle queries. So, I'm trying to create a function that will just return tables. Hmm, can I use pipelined or package function, or what? Can you give me an advice? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try another approach - instead of chaging table data - just SELECT what you need?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I just disregard the DMLs and using the table. Thanks for you response! :)

Answer (score 0):

This was so complicated.
For the reason that I want to get records from a table to crystal report, I put what I select to a table.

Now, I realized that I can place the logic from my procedure into the function, put it into a `SYS_REFCURSOR`, return it and call the function using this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(GETDEPLOYMENT_COMPUTER('2012'));
```

Thanks, anyways, for those who response and helped me. :)